# Prepare headings and footer with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, books, parts

I am writing a book in LaTeX, where I want to have the title of the part on the heading of the odd pages and the title of the chapter on the heading of the even pages, and the footer with text "copyright" closer to the page number. But I don't get it.

Problems that I have:

- I don't know the command to write the title of the part
- The margins that I have with `\geometry` don't affect the headings and the footers.
- The footer of the first page of the chapter is not following the structure of  "$\copyright$Copyright page number".

This is the code that I am using. Thank you in advance

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}


\fancyhead[RO]{Name of the part}

\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}

\fancyfoot[LE]{  \thepage\qquad  $\copyright$ Copyright}

\fancyfoot[RO]{ $\copyright$ Copyright\qquad \thepage}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\chaptername
        \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    

\geometry{
    paperwidth = 17cm,
    paperheight = 24cm,
}

\usepackage[a4, center, cross, noinfo]{crop}

\begin{document}

\part[Short title of part]
{Long title of part}


\chapter[Title of chapter]
{Long title of chapter}

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: \part in book class does not store the title, neither as a macro nor as \leftmark or \rightmark.  \title (used by \maketitle) will store it as \@title.  You could just put the title into \rightmark using \markboth (in \chaptermark).

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a redefinition of `\part` so that the short part title from the optional argument (or the long one if there is no optional argument) is put in a variable, that then is used in the header.

**EDIT**: I redefine page style `plain` to have only the footer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth = 17cm,paperheight = 24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\originalpart}{} % trigger an error if already defined
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\let\originalpart\part
\RenewDocumentCommand{\part}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \part*
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\renewcommand\parttitle{#3}}
       {\renewcommand\parttitle{#2}}%
      \originalpart*{#3}
    }%
    {% normal \part
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\renewcommand\parttitle{#3}\originalpart{#3}}
       {\renewcommand\parttitle{#2}\originalpart[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RO]{\parttitle}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE]{  \thepage~$\copyright$ Copyright}
\fancyfoot[RO]{ $\copyright$ Copyright\qquad \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}% no header
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{}% no header rule
  % footer is "inherited" from fancy
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\chaptername
        \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    
\usepackage[a4, center, cross, noinfo]{crop}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part[Short title of part1]
{Long title of part1}

\chapter[Title of chapter1]
{Long title of chapter}     \lipsum[2-17]

\part[Short title of part2]
{Long title of part2}
\chapter[Title of chapter2]
{Long title of chapter} \lipsum[2-20]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! However, the footer of the first page of the chapter is not following the structure of  "$\copyright$Copyright page number". Do you know what should I change?

Comment: That is because the first page of a chapter uses page style `plain`, not `fancy`. You probably don't want headers on this page, only the footer. This can be done by redefining page style `plain`. I will add that to the solution.

Comment: That's it, thank you

Comment: I have just realised that the code doesn't work properly when one part ends and starts a new one. The title of the new part appears in the previous part. See it with this example on page 8: \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \part[Short title of part1]
 {Long title of part1}
 
 \chapter[Title of chapter1]
 {Long title of chapter}     \lipsum[2-17]
 \part[Short title of part2]
 {Long title of part2}
 \chapter[Title of chapter2]
 {Long title of chapter} \lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}

Comment: It has been solved adding \newpage
before \part

Comment: Your code works properly, but I need something to change. How could I write the number of the part before the title? For instance: "Part I: Short title of part 1" Thanks in advance

Comment: I have solved adding it manually to the short title :P

Comment: The problem is that it appears now in the Table of Contents: "I. Parte I:"

Answer (score 1):

The `\part` command issues `\markboth{}{}`, but it's easy to change it (actually `\@part`) in order that it issues `\partmark{#1}` like `\chapter` issues `\chaptermark{#1}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary for Spanish
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[a4, center, cross, noinfo]{crop}

\geometry{
    paperwidth = 17cm,
    paperheight = 24cm,
}


\usepackage{lipsum} % for mok text

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage\qquad  $\copyright$ Copyright}
\fancyfoot[RO]{$\copyright$ Copyright\qquad \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[RO]{$\copyright$ Copyright\qquad \thepage}%
}

\newcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{}{}} % like the default
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\markboth{}{}}{\partmark{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\partname\ \thepart.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    

\begin{document}

\part[Short title of part]
{Long title of part}


\chapter[Title of chapter]
{Long title of chapter}

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I believe you want the part title on even pages and the chapter title on odd ones. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I want only the title of the part in even pages, without "Part I" and the chapter in odd pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility to manipulate the distance between page number and copyright:

```
\fancyfoot[RO]{ $\copyright$ Copyright\hspace{0.5cm}% instead of\qquad
\thepage}
```

or

```
\fancyfoot[LE]{  \thepage~% ~instead of \qquad, you can use ~~ for a double space as well
$\copyright$ Copyright}
```

Instead of defining geometry parameters apart, you have to put them as options after \usepackage:

```
 \usepackage[paperwidth = 17cm,paperheight = 24cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! However, the footer of the first page of the chapter is not following the structure of "$\copyright$Copyright page number". Do you know what should I change?