# Problems with headers and table content

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering, parts

I have the following code to define the style of a book, but I have three problems.

1st the number of the pages in the table of contents is not correct

2nd I want to have in the header the title of the part that the chapter belongs to in the even pages. See on page number 8 that I have as header the title of part 2, but it belongs to part 1.

3rd The header of the table of content should be 'Índice' instead of 'INDICE'.

Thanks in advance,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %Niveles de titulos
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    %Niveles en TOC


\usepackage[paperwidth = 17cm,paperheight = 24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand{\originalpart}{} % trigger an error if already defined
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\let\originalpart\part
\RenewDocumentCommand{\part}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \part*
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#3}}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#2}}%
        \originalpart*{#3}
    }%
    {% normal \part
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#3}\originalpart{#3}}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#2}\originalpart[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\parttitle}
\fancyfoot[LE]{  \thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{ \thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
    \fancyhead{}% no header
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{}% no header rule
    % footer is "inherited" from fancy
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
}

\addto\captionsspanish{
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Índice}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\chaptername
        \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    
\usepackage[a4, center, cross, noinfo]{crop}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part[Short title of part1]
    {Long title of part1}
    
    \chapter[Title of chapter1]
    {Long title of chapter}     \lipsum[2-17]
    
    \part[Short title of part2]
    {Long title of part2}
    \chapter[Title of chapter2]
    {Long title of chapter} \lipsum[2-20]
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}\chapter*{Appendix} \lipsum[2-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer. Below is a revision of your MWE which does almost what you want but with a fixed part title text in the header. I did nothing about the title of the ToC which was printed as Indice.

```
% bookheadtocprob.tex  SE 602257

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %Niveles de titulos
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    %Niveles en TOC


\usepackage[paperwidth = 17cm,paperheight = 24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{comment}
%%% I don't understand this

\newcommand{\originalpart}{} % trigger an error if already defined
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\let\originalpart\part
\RenewDocumentCommand{\part}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \part*
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#3}}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#2}}%
        \originalpart*{#3}
    }%
    {% normal \part
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#3}\originalpart{#3}}
        {\renewcommand\parttitle{#2}\originalpart[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
}

\end{comment}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\parttitle}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\the\part parttitle}
\fancyhead[LE]{Parttitle \thepart}  %% just to show the Part number
\fancyfoot[LE]{  \thepage \hspace{0.5cm} $\copyright$ Ediciones Paraninfo}
\fancyfoot[RO]{ $\copyright$ Ediciones Paraninfo \hspace{0.5cm} \thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
    \fancyhead{}% no header
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{}% no header rule
    % footer is "inherited" from fancy
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
}

\addto\captionsspanish{
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Índice}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\chaptername
        \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    
\usepackage[a4, center, cross, noinfo]{crop}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part[Short title of part1]
    {Long title of part1}
    
    \chapter[Title of chapter1]
    {Long title of chapter}     \lipsum[2-17]
    
    \part[Short title of part2]
    {Long title of part2}
    \chapter[Title of chapter2]
    {Long title of chapter} \lipsum[2-20]
    
%%%% wrong order
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}\chapter*{Appendix} \lipsum[2-20]
\chapter*{Appendix}    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} \lipsum[2-20]
\end{document}
```

Note that the page header in the Appendix refers to the previous chapter so you probably need to do something about that. I think that there is a problem with your redefinition of `\part` which I did not understand so I commented it out and got the part headers on the appropriate pages.

Comment: About the code that you don't understand, I don't understand it either. I am just a beginner, and it was the answer to a previous question I asked here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597917/prepare-headings-and-footer-with-fancyhdr/597929#597929

Comment: Thank you for showing me that the solution of question 1 was to change the order to \chapter*{Appendix}    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} \lipsum[2-20]
\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

The second question has been solved adding `\newpage`
before `\part`